# Outputing contents to CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I use this site alot while learning Powershell. Its been a great help so far!

Here is my issue:

I am trying to write a script that will take workstation names, pull the workstation description from WMI and **output both the workstation name and description found into a new .csv file**.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Get-Content -Path "workstation_names.csv" | Select-Object Workstations |
Foreach-Object { Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $workstations | Select Workstations, Description | Export-CSV -Path "results.csv" -NoTypeInformation }
```

The `workstation_names.csv` has a column named "Workstations" and under it each cell has a single workstation name in it. Currently my script will create an output file that will have two columns in it. One called "Workstations" and the other called "Description". The Workstation column is empty, and the Description column only has the results for the first workstation description in it (even though I have 10 workstation names listed in the `workstation_names.csv` file).

I am sitting here scratching my head with my n00bish knowledge of Powershell. I know I PROBABLY need to so something with the array that is created from the first `.csv` file but I am not sure how to code what I need. Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4c74356b41's script will fail for several reasons

- It's `-header` not -headers
- there is a typo %_ instead of `$_`
- `select Workstations` won't work as that's no property of gwmi

This only slightly reworked script should do.

```
$inFile = "workstation_names.csv"
$results = @()
Import-CSV -path $inFile -header Workstations |
  % {$results += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem `
     -ComputerName $_.Workstations | Select PSComputerName, Description} 
$results | Export-Csv -Path "results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

To see which properties are available see the following output

```
GWmi -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost|gm|out-gridview
```

Comment: thanks, i was supposing he checked what properties are there :) and sorry for the typos

Comment: Yowza, I was way off. This works exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks so much for the feedback and help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this should do the trick:

```
$inFile = "workstation_names.csv"
$results = @()
Import-CSV -path $inFile -header Workstations |
  % {$results += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem `
     -ComputerName $_.Workstations | Select PSComputerName, Description} 
$results | Export-Csv -Path "results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

So to elaborate on this, you aren't really importing the CSV, you are importing the raw text file, which is confusing, since I don't really understand how anything works for you in that case. Here the script will create an array to store the results, import file as CSV, loop through the valuables and output results to the CSV.

Comment: Why not pipe directly to `Export-Csv`? (ie. `ForEach-Object {...} |Export-Csv ...`)

Comment: well, i guess you could do that.